# Display proper Date using Text field in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a view that goes as follows:

```
<f:content>
                <core:Title text="Student" />
                <Label text="Name" />
                <Text text="{fullName}" />
                <Label text="Date of Birth" />
                <Text text="{dob}" />
```

The {dob} is the value that is being fetched from the Database.
When the value is displayed it is displayed as:

```
Date of Birth :2015-12-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

I want it to be displayed only 2015-12-30.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to define a formatter this way:

```
<Text text = "{ path: 'dob', formatter: 'my.Formatter.formatDate' }" />
```

And in js:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.Formatter");

my.Formatter = {
  formatDate : function (value) {// value is the date   
    return "xx"; // return the formatted date
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @toskv it Worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Text text ="{path:'dob', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions : { style:'medium', UTC: true}}"/>
```

This is cleaner solution according to me, unless you have special formatting of Date apart from what SAP provides.

Read more about [`sap.ui.model.type.Date`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.Date.html) & for
date format options [explore here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.TypeDateAsDate/preview).